# Display activity indicator only after clicking the button

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, activity-indicator

hi I’m trying view the activity indicator by clicking the button. I have tried but i having some issues. If i drag the activity indicator to my storyboard but its visible while running my app i want to display while clicking the button. in my app I’m giving the photo upload option. So if they click the upload button i want to view the activity indicator . ..

this is code i have tired but its not working.

this is my h file where i have implemented the activity indicator and the button..

```
- (IBAction)click:(id)sender;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;
```

this is code which i have used in my m file...

```
-(void)temp
{
 spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
 spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0);
 [spinner setCenter:CGPointMake(480/2.0, 128.0/2)]; // (mid of screen) I do this because I'm in landscape mode
 [self.view addSubview:spinner];
 [spinner startAnimating];
 [spinner release];
}
```

and im calling this function in my button..

```
- (IBAction)click:(id)sender {
[self temp];
}
```

and also im have some other issues i saw the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841385/how-start-animation-of-activity-indicator-when-click-on-button) the problem is

```
[yourView addSubview:spinner];
```

in yourview i give my uiviewcontroller name but its giving error i have changed to

```
[self.view addSubview:spinner];
```

pls tell me where im doing wrong and what is the right way to make it.. thanks

Comment: what happens when you click that button?

Comment: nothing happens it remains same the activity indicator is not working @SuryakantSharma

Comment: did activity indicator not displays at all?

Comment: If you have the spinner connected to your view, why do you need to add it as a sub view? There's no point. Alternatively you can create a new one which is not connected to your view.

Comment: not its not displaying @SuryakantSharma

Comment: yeah @IdanMoshe is right if you added activity indicator in your xib/storyboard than why you are creating again in "temp" method?

Comment: ya ur right first i have tried with without connecting its not working so i have tried with this.. @IdanMoshe

Comment: @user3247287 I assume you have your spinner connected to your view, please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man I got the problem...I think you are adding white activity indicator on white view that's why it is not being display but it is there for sure so...use some other style `UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray`

```
-(void)temp
{
 spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
 spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0);
 [spinner setCenter:CGPointMake(480/2.0, 128.0/2)]; // (mid of screen) I do this because I'm in landscape mode
 [self.view addSubview:spinner];
 [spinner startAnimating];
 [spinner release];
}
```

Comment: @Suryankant Sharama its working thanks but i view to give the some time interview for the activity controller pls tell me how to make it

Comment: sorry I didn't get you.

Comment: use - (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay;

Answer (score 0):

First of all since you already have an IBOutlet for the spinner so do not allocate a new one in temp method. Modify your temp method to look like this:

```
  -(void)temp
    {
      spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0);
     [spinner setCenter:CGPointMake(480/2.0, 128.0/2)]; // (mid of screen) I do this because I'm in landscape mode
     [self.view addSubview:spinner];
     [spinner startAnimating];
    }
```

Comment: pls tell how to make without using the iboutlet

Comment: completely remove the spinner from the XIB and use your original temp method. it should work

Comment: after removing that its im getting error like use of undeclared identifier 'spinner' so pls tell me where i have to declare the spinner @Ratikanata Patra

Comment: instead of spinner use self.spinner

Comment: ya i have tried that one its give error like object spinner is not in the viewcontroller

Comment: have you removed this line :@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;???

Comment: s i have removed the that line @Ratikanata Patra

Comment: put it the line back. and remove IBOutlet i.e keep this line
@property (strong, nonatomic)UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;

Comment: thanks Ratikanta Patra ur help its working i have used the above code given by @Suryakant Sharma

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your spinner connected to your view.
In your `viewDidLoad` you can setup your view, then it'll show when you tap the button:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    self.spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0);
    [self.spinner setCenter:CGPointMake(480/2.0, 128.0/2)]; // (mid of screen) I do this because I'm in landscape mode
    self.spinner.hidden = YES;
}

- (IBAction)click:(id)sender
{
    self.spinner.hidden = NO;
    [self.spinner startAnimating];

     // Additionally you can show spinner in top bar
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
}

- (void)stopSpinner
{
    if (self.spinner.isAnimating) {
        self.spinner.hidden = YES;
        [self.spinner stopAnimating];

        // And hide it when you don't need it anymore
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    }
}
```

I suggest you see this answer: [How to get orientation-dependent height and width of the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905432/how-to-get-orientation-dependent-height-and-width-of-the-screen/13756020#13756020) to re position your spinner.

Comment: i have make it with out using IBOutlet activity indicator pls tell me how to make it i remove the IBOutlet it its showing error

Comment: You can 'ctrl+drag your spinner to the correct outlet using storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I f you are using interface builder like **Storyboard** or **XIB** then just set the frame and evrything there itself. And if you want to change the property of it at runtime just use the **IBOutlet** you have used.
You need not to instantiate again just use its getter and setter to use it accordingly. So here you can do.

```
- (IBAction)click:(id)sender 
  {
    [self.spinner startAnimating];
  }
```

and synthesize **spinner** before using it.

And if you want to use it programmatically delete it from XIB and remove all references corresponding to it. And declare in .h file

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;
```

or you can make a property

```
@property(nonatomic, strong)UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;
```

and just use your own code.